# Set reminder on a project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reminders

Is there a way to set a reminder on certain projects/solutions in visual studio 2010?

something like a pop-up message that show up whenever the project opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like [this](http://stickynotes4code.com/) be suitable?

Here is a screenshot of the plugin being used to do something similar to what you're asking, just in VS2008 instead:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that what i want, but i will give it a try

Comment: @Star I mean this is a screenshot of it being used in the VS2008 - http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/StickyNotes - kinda looks similar to what you're asking, and I'm sure it's available to use in the VS2010 version.

Comment: it is available to VS 2010 , not what wanted really but i think it will do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Star sorry for that, I will have a check to see if there's any better alternatives and comment here if I can find one.